# localNotifications trigger fires immediately

Tags: ionic-framework, localnotification

The trigger doesn't work properly.It fires immediately. Can you tell why?

```
  this.localNotifications.schedule({

    id: i,
    title: 'Hey1',
    text: "Time to train again!",
    trigger: { every: { hour: hours, minute: minutes } },

  });
```

Comment: can you post the hours and minutes values/

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman

They are numbers:i get the values from the user input and i turn them to numbers .The user can pick from 0-23 for hours, adn 0-60 for minutes.

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman what i want to acomplish is that the notification fires everyday at the users input time